# Pandas apply function, receiving KeyError 'Column Name'

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset has a column called `age` and I'm trying to count the null values.

I know it can be easily achieved by doing something like `len(df) - df['age'].count()`. However, I'm playing around with functions and just like to apply the function to calculate the null count.

Here is what I have:

```
def age_is_null(df):
    age_col = df['age']
    null = df[age_col].isnull()
    age_null = df[null]
    return len(age_null)

count = df.apply(age_is_null)
print (count)
```

When I do that, I received an error: `KeyError: 'age'`.

Can someone tells me why I'm getting that error and what should I change in the code to make it work?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how `apply` works. Check in the docs what kind of functions you can use with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) or pass DataFrame to function here:

```
#function should be simplify
def age_is_null(df):
    return df['age'].isnull().sum()


count = df.pipe(age_is_null)
print (count)
```

---

```
count = age_is_null(df)
print (count)
```

Error means if use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) then iterate by columns, so it failed if want select column `age`.

```
def func(x):
   print (x)

df.apply(func)
```

EDIT: For selecting column use column name:

```
def age_is_null(df):
    age_col = 'age' <- here
    null = df[age_col].isnull()
    age_null = df[null]
    return len(age_null)
```

Or pass selected column for mask:

```
def age_is_null(df):
    age_col = df['age']
    null = age_col.isnull()  <- here
    age_null = df[null]
    return len(age_null)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. When I used your code, it works out great. However, I'm more trying to understand why it didn't work for my original code. I left my function as it is and changed the count = df.pipe(age_is_null)  and then print (count). It still gives me an error. The difference between the output of your function and my function is you have a type numpy.int32, and my is int. Is that the main reason why it didn't work for me?

Comment: I did have try to pass the dataframe which means I have tried count = age_is_null(df) before I posted this question, and that's the error message I got and it is the same error message as I changed to pipe instead of apply.  ""None of [Float64Index([22.0, 38.0, 26.0, 35.0, 35.0,  nan, 54.0,  2.0, 27.0, 14.0,\n              ...\n              33.0, 22.0, 28.0, 25.0, 39.0, 27.0, 19.0,  nan, 26.0, 32.0],\n             dtype='float64', length=891)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: @MkD - there was double selecting, edited answer for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a function, you can Try this

```
df[df["age"].isnull() == True].shape
```

Comment: You don't really need the ` == True` part, you can just ues `df[df["age"].isnull()]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass dataframe df while calling the function age_is_null.That's why age column is not recognised.

```
count = df.apply(age_is_null(df))
```

Comment: I didn't check whole code but when I tried to use age_is_null() it give the error-                                  TypeError: age_is_null() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'